# What software can I download to my Mac to convert mkv to mp4?

Tags: media-converter

I am looking for a tool that will convert my mkv file to an mp4 file, but is devoid of malware and bloatware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FFMpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)  It's a command line program but it can convert a MKV to a MP4 without recompressing the file.  Very quick.

The command to do so would be
`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy -c:s mov_text output.mp4`

If you do some further digging, you can probably find a script to help.  Actually, you might look at [this Apple.StackExchange answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/131655).

Answer (score 1):

I use [Permute](https://software.charliemonroe.net/permute) on a regular basis, although it is subscription based.

If you prefer open source:

[Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr) for GUI.

[FFMPG](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg) for CLI.